# mkdir in /tmp not working: "Permission Denied"

Tags: c++, linux, mkdir

I am trying to write a program to handle logging for an app. This is supposed to write logs to `/tpm/app-name/log.txt`. In order to do this, I need to make the directory `app-name` before writing, in case it doesn't exist. However, my code will not make the directory even though it runs with the correct permissions to do so.

I have tried:
 * using `chdir` to move to `/tmp`, and making the `app-name` directory afterwards
 * running the program with root privs (this is less than desirable and makes the code error out because of line 65 not having access to the current environment the rest of the system is running in).

I would like this program to be able to work from anywhere in the system.

My current code, in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        string name = argv[1];
        string DIR = "/tmp/" + name;
        string LOG_LOCATION = DIR + "/log.txt";
        int len = DIR.length();
        char LOG_DIR[len + 1];
        strcpy(LOG_DIR, DIR.c_str());
        string OUTPUT_LOG = "Some error log text";
        ofstream log;
        cout << OUTPUT_LOG << endl;
        if (mkdir(LOG_DIR, 1777) == -1)
        {
            cerr << "ERROR:  " << strerror(errno) << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Directory created";
        }
        log.open (LOG_LOCATION);
        log << OUTPUT_LOG << endl;
        log.close();
}
```

When using this program, the code compiles fine and even runs fine. It just doesn't make the directory, like I expect it to. Because of this, it also does not make the log file.

Thanks!

Comment: Try and replicate the problem in your shell. On some systems `tmpfs` is not the same as the regular filesystem, it's isolated per-process. See [questions like this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181937/how-create-a-temporary-file-in-shell-script) for examples that talk about [`mktemp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autogen/mktemp.html).

Comment: Possibly you should be using `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`

Comment: Just a thought: how about using existing logging infrastructure? for example http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html

Comment: Probably not the main bug, but: you might want to change 1777 to 01777.

Comment: @tadman I tried replicating it in my shell and it worked. I checked to see if it is a `tmpfs` using `df -T` and it didn't appear to be.

Comment: Please try to come up with a **minimal** example. 90% of your code have nothing to do with creating a directory.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick this will definitely prevent creation of the file inside the directory.

Comment: @n.m. I think I got it minimalized properly. Not sure if it will compile now but it should. The general premise of what i am trying to do should still be apparent tho.

Comment: 1777 doesn't do what you think it does, read other commments.

Comment: Oh and please stop using  bits/stdc++.h for Bob's sake.

Comment: @n.m. I set 1777 to that number because it is same hex permission set as /tmp. As for bits/stdc++, I am pretty new to C++. All I know is that it needs to work and I can't have data leaks. Beyond that I would prefer we **all** focus on the bug I asked about initially, because that is the crucial part of this keeping the program from working in the first place. Thank you for your understanding. Sorry if that comes across as rude.

Comment: Try not to push back against advice. C++ is a tricky beast at the best of times and often simplifying your code, removing junk that doesn't need to be there, and steering away from anti-patterns and bad practices helps minimize the trouble of implementing it correctly. You don't have to use every piece of advice, but you should at least listen and take it under advisement.

Comment: Permissions are usually specified as octal numbers, not hex. 1777 is neither octal nor hex. It is a decimal number. Decimal 1777 is not a valid permission mask. You need an octal 1777. Octal numbers are spelled with a leading zero in C++: 01777. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @n.m. 
I have tried the suggested octal number and I am getting a "No such file or directory" error now.

Comment: You may want to ask a question with updated code, together with its **exact** output, and also your method of checking your results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I feel really stupid here, but I figured out what the answer to my own issue was.

Firstly, I was passing the wrong info on stdin (the program was using this info to create the correct folder and I had the input on one of the options formatted wrong so it couldn't make the folder).

Secondly, as @Mark Plotnick pointed out in the fourth comment, and as several others mentioned later on, I needed to add a leading zero to my the permission set on the line with mkdir.

Moral of the story: make sure you pass the correct info on stdin and get your permissions right. XD